# React App refreshes on prop change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-intl

I am implementing Yahoo React-Intl to localize my application. In order to do this I must wrap the ROOT with the Localizer like so:

```
const Root = React.createClass({

 childContextTypes: {
     refresh: React.PropTypes.func
 },

 getChildContext() {
     return {
         refresh: () => this.forceUpdate()
     }
 },

 render() {
   let { language, messages } = this.props;
     return (
         <Provider store={store }>
           <IntlProvider locale="en" messages= { messages } >
             <Router history={browserHistory}>
             </Router>
           </IntlProvider>
         </Provider>
       )
   }
 }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
   language: state.currentLanguage.language,
   messages: state.currentLanguage.messages
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Root)
```

With "messages" being a JSON object containing key value translation mappings.

My problem is that I have to make this dynamic so that the user can choose to change languages. I have created  an Action/Reducer combo in order to change objects assigned to the messages prop within the application state.  However, when I call the action and feed messages a new object, the entire pages refreshes and my state goes back to initial values.

Messages by default is a null variable and is assigned an object containing id values to chinese characters. When given the object by default, the translations are seen correctly. It is only when I update it via action that the application refreshes and the desired results are not obtained.

What may be causing my application to refresh?

Comment: How are you updating it?

Comment: I call an action that which assigns "messages" the value of another JSON object in the reducer

Comment: @DaveNewton I have updated the code with more details left by the passed programmer. Could it be the two functions at the top causing this problem?

Comment: The forceUpdate is suspicious, but I don't know enough about it to help-sorry!